# Windows Version of Ubuntu One staying?

Tags: ubuntu-one, windows-7

I am wondering if there will definitely be a Windows Version of Ubuntu One after the beta? Because otherwise I will not bother getting a 20gb plan as I dont use Ubuntu on any pc.

Comment: I'm interested to know what it is that attracts you to ubuntu one as a non ubuntu user?

Comment: One of the key benefits of Ubuntu One service vs others is the integration with desktop applications. Even if they keep supporting the windows client you shouldn't expect the same level of support you get for the Ubuntu client.

Comment: I suspect troll.

Comment: in the endeffect ubuntu one is cheaper than say dropbox which costs 9,99$ a month for 50gb vs 29,99$ a year for 20gb. i just want something where i can backup some files for not that much money.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there will be a windows client after the beta. Currently we have the beta to test the interaction with the desktop and the possible problems that we will have.

Regarding the interaction with the desktop, we are also porting desktopcouch to work n windows which should bring your contacts to that platform. Tomboy sync already works on windows and there are plans to help banshee to be ported to windows so that we can offer th music store there.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. so i guess its worth it to get a one year 20gb plan.

Comment: It is, although I would wait until we get out of beta :)